# Are third party chargers for iPhone bad despite having government agencies' certification stamps?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging, charger, charge

My usage history with Apple: iPhone 3 (2011~2013) and iPhone 8 (2018~present)

I sometimes used chargers purchased from convenience stores. Although all the chargers I got had government certification marks on them, so I thought they were 'originals' sanctioned from the manufacturers themselves, they were actually manufactured by third (usually Chinese) parties.

I did ask the government agency about this and the person in charge said that they were indeed safe(although I think there was a miscommunication such that he took the charger to be something else).

I also asked the Apple service desk for advice and they said the iPhone battery was designed to ward off overheating from unsuitable third party chargers.

Can an expert verify any of these answers here? Was there any danger in using these(in particular the danger of being electrocuted or damaging the smartphone).

Comment: Please see the [Help Centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about how to write effective questions.

Comment: You've asked two persons who should know, and now expect a few anonymous persons on an internet site to confirm this? Not sure this will improve anything.